# How to access many to one associations in Sencha Touch 2 tpl

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have 2 models - messages and users - each message has one user. I am loading a json file of messages with nested user data - my models have their relationships defined already.

```
[{"message_id":"1","user":{"user_id":"2","name":"Bob"},"text":"This is a sample message that is here as a placeholder until we have real comments"}...
```

In my template I would like to access the user data - but {user.name} does not yield anything.

Anyone have an example? It seems I have to parse this myself but not sure where to begin

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `<tpl for="user">{name}</tpl>` to display the nested data.